# What is meant by a partially-initialized module and fully-initialized module?

Tags: python, module

What is meant by a partially-initialized module and fully-initialized module? I searched for it on Google but couldn't find anything related to it.

Comment: Could you please provide more details, where and why did you get this error? Btw look in to the following link before you ask [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @BForce Circular imports.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what it says in plain English: the module's initialization is incomplete.  This is in reference to an error message, typically for a missing symbol definition.

The reason behind this is that you imported a file, which starts the initialization process.  During this process, a required symbol proved to be undefined, almost always due to an unintended circular reference.

A simple search for `+partially defined Python module` will bring you plenty of use cases.  I hope the above explanation bridges your gap in understanding the issue.